# OrientDB - match query for recommender

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am trying to solve a simple MATCH query using OrientDB.

I would recommend for user A that bougth product P in common to user B.

When I try this query i Receive an error that states "an error to line 1 column 33"

```
SELECT d1.UserId, d2.UserId FROM (
  MATCH 
  {class:User, as: U1} -buy-> {class:Product, as:P},
  {class:User, as: U2} -buy-> {as:P},
  {as:U2} -buy-> {class:Product, as P2}
  RETURN U1 as d1, U2 as d2, O as o
)
```

Do you have any suggestion in order solve my issue?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1):

You miss a `:` at the end of last pattern, just try the following

```
SELECT d1.UserId, d2.UserId FROM (
  MATCH 
  {class:User, as: U1} -buy-> {class:Product, as:P},
  {class:User, as: U2} -buy-> {as:P},
  {as:U2} -buy-> {class:Product, as:P2}
  RETURN U1 as d1, U2 as d2, O as o
)
```

Comment: Thanks Luigi for the help, it was a terrible typo. Anyway, I have seen the performance of match statement are limited. Do you have any idea about potential improvement to suggest me?

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: How big is your DB? you are not filtering the query in any way, so you can expect it to scan all the db...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I think the best solution is

```
SELECT d1.UserId, d2.UserId FROM (
  MATCH 
  {class:User, as: U1, where: (UserId=12345) } -buy-> {class:Product, as:P},
  {class:User, as: U2, where: (UserId<>12345)} -buy-> {as:OP},
  {as:U2} -buy-> {class:Product, as:P2}
  RETURN U2 as d2, P, OP
)
```

Thanks for all the help.

R.